# Unable to match input value to any allowed input type for the field error - Prisma -Seed

Tags: typescript, sqlite, prisma, seeding

Running seed command `tsx prisma/seed.ts` ... it failed to create a post as it returns an error

→ 6     await prisma.habit.create(
Failed to validate the query: `Unable to match input value to any allowed input type for the field. Parse errors: [Query parsing/validation error at` Mutation.createOneHabit.data.HabitCreateInput.created_at`: A value is required but not set., Query parsing/validation error at` Mutation.createOneHabit.data.HabitUncheckedCreateInput.created_at`: A value is required but not set.]` at `Mutation.createOneHabit.data`
at Object.handleRequestError (/Users/luistigre/www/nlw/nlw/aulas/server/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:31941:13)
at Object.handleAndLogRequestError (/Users/luistigre/www/nlw/nlw/aulas/server/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:31913:12)
at Object.request (/Users/luistigre/www/nlw/nlw/aulas/server/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:31908:12)
at PrismaClient._request (/Users/luistigre/www/nlw/nlw/aulas/server/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:32994:16)
at main (/Users/luistigre/www/nlw/nlw/aulas/server/prisma/seed.ts:6:5) {
code: 'P2009',
clientVersion: '4.9.0',
meta: {
query_validation_error: 'Unable to match input value to any allowed input type for the field. Parse errors: [Query parsing/validation error at `Mutation.createOneHabit.data.HabitCreateInput.created_at`: A value is required but not set., Query parsing/validation error at `Mutation.createOneHabit.data.HabitUncheckedCreateInput.created_at`: A value is required but not set.]',
query_position: 'Mutation.createOneHabit.data'
},
batchRequestIdx: undefined
}

An error occurred while running the seed command:
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: tsx prisma/seed.ts

SCHEMA.PRISMA

```js
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator erd {
  provider = "prisma-erd-generator"
}

model Habit {
  id         String   @id @default(uuid())
  title      String
  created_at DateTime

  dayHabits DayHabit[]
  weekDays  HabitWeekDays[]

  @@map("habits")
}

model HabitWeekDays {
  id       String @id @default(uuid())
  habit_id String
  week_day Int

  habit Habit @relation(fields: [habit_id], references: [id])

  @@unique([habit_id, week_day])
  @@map("habit_week_days")
}

model Day {
  id        String     @id @default(uuid())
  date      DateTime
  dayHabits DayHabit[]

  @@unique([date])
  @@map("days")
}

model DayHabit {
  id       String @id @default(uuid())
  day_id   String
  habit_id String

  day   Day   @relation(fields: [day_id], references: [id])
  habit Habit @relation(fields: [habit_id], references: [id])

  @@unique([day_id, habit_id])
  @@map("day_habits")
}
```

SEED.TS FILE

```js
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

async function main() {
    await prisma.habit.create({
        data: {
            title: 'Beber 2L de água',
            created_at: new Date('2023-01-10T00:00:00:000z')
        }
    })
    
}


main()
    .then(async () => {
        await prisma.$disconnect()
    })
    .catch(async (e) => {
        console.error(e)
        await prisma.$disconnect()
        process.exit(1)
    })
```

PACKAGE.JS

```
 "prisma": {
      "seed": "tsx prisma/seed.ts"
  }
```

I was expecting it to be able to save into the database

Comment: You need to also enter data for fields `dayHabits` and `weekDays` field as they are both required in the Habit schema. fields with [] makes a field a list and cannot be optional. See this [section](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#-modifier) of the documentation and this other [section](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model) for modelling data in Prisma

Answer (score 1):

try changing this:

```
created_at: new Date('2023-01-22T00:00.000z')
```

for this:

```
created_at: new Date('2023-01-22')
```

or just this to get the current date:

```
created_at: new Date()
```

the function new Date('2023-01-22T00:00.000z') returns an invalid date, you can check by running a console.log in the browser or in a TS file executed by node